# Why does Windows Explorer randomly lock random folders

Tags: windows-10, user-folders

There are times when I can't rename a folder on an external hard drive because Explorer is "locking" it. I have to first unlock it using software. There is no apparent reason for Explorer to lock random folders. As the administrator, I have full permissions over all folders.

[image]

Comment: In my experience, this is a common occurrence when your workstation is connected to a domain network, *or* when you are modifying a folder located on a file server/network drive/SMB share, etc.  You can test by logging into your workstation's **local** admin account and see if you can reproduce the behavior or not (or try booting into safe-mode without network).  I've also seen instances when UNC paths get too long, you start seeing buggy behavior through `explorer.exe`.

Comment: I have seen cases where an over-active antivirus kept locking files and causing problems. The solution was to uninstall this antivirus.

Comment: @Arctiic Although I am working on a local account, the folders DO sync to a network server. But when I randomly check folders, they are not locked. This lock thing happens randomly even after the files have been synced weeks ago.

Comment: @harrymc I only use Microsoft's built-in defender and don't have 3rd party AV software.

Comment: Try disabling the Preview Pane in Explorer (if enabled).

Comment: @harrymc I never use the preview pane.

Comment: Some software is doing the locking. You can use for example [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to try and figure out which startup is responsible.